# How to reference a specific version of NetStandard in project.json?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, project.json

I am struggling to figure out how to force the npm (*Nuget Package Manager*) to resolve a specific version of the NetStandard1.X platform.

I am trying to use [Serilog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/serilog) but the version of .NetStandard it supports is v1.3. Is there any way to force this behavior in the project.json file via some command or switch or option.

```
        {
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "Serilog": "2.2.1"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.3": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50",
      "dependencies": {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When you **specify v1.3**, you end up with **v1.6**. Surely there must be a way of doing this? I am trying to upgrade an old .net framework 4.6 class library that was using log4net and I am struggling with the basics here.

***Error Dump:***

```
Package Serilog 2.2.1 is not compatible with netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6). Package Serilog 2.2.1 supports:
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - net46 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6)
  - netstandard1.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.0)
  - netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3)
One or more packages are incompatible with .NETStandard,Version=v1.6.
```

***DotNet Core Version Info:***

Product Information:

Version: 1.0.0-preview2-003131

Commit SHA-1 hash:  635cf40e58

Comment: You can use `nLog` instead of `log4net`, it has an extension package for .Net Core.

Comment: Which version of .Net Core do you have installed? Your project.json restores on my machine with no problems.

Comment: Thanks but I think that's the SDK version.
I am using .Net Core 1.0.1. You can run `dotnet` in your command prompt to get the framework's version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124800/discussion-between-ibrarmumtaz-and-ignas).

Comment: Log4net is being ported to .net core. 

GitHub: https://github.com/apache/log4net

Comment: I think that error could be caused by an outdated version of NuGet. Try updating that.

Comment: Is there a command for that and whats the easiest way to check that? I have version: 3.5.0.1484 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `project.json` restores on my machine correctly, so I would guess there is something wrong with packages/versioning.

Please try to change `Serilog` dependency version:

```
"Serilog": "2.3.0-dev-00711"
```

Or as you suggested yourself during our chat, move the decency into `framework` tag:

```
"frameworks": { 
    "netstandard1.6": { 
        "imports": "dotnet5.6", 
        "dependencies": { 
            "Serilog": "2.3.0-dev-00711" 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Not sure why i was getting so many type compatibility problems but upgrading to a new package helped. =). Hopefully this is not an issue for other devs as it looks like v1.6 is backwards compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand what the question is or what exactly is the problem you're having.

But one thing that jumps at me about your project.json is that the version of `NETStandard.Library` should be `1.6.0`, even if you're targeting `netstandard1.3`. (Yes, it's confusing.)

Comment: yes i understand and it is very confusing but the package from Serilog is only compatible with netstandard 1.3.0 . The compiler throws up an error about this and is very specific about this compatibility issue.

Comment: netstandard.library is a nuget package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/NETStandard.Library/1.6.0) which contains a set of modules/dlls. This library support many .net standard versions: 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3. The nuget version doesn't match the version numbers of the .net standard release.