# Does FluentAssertions support Test projects that are .NET Core 2.0?

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I have a Class Library (.NET Core 2.0) being tested by an MSTest Test Project (.NET Core 2.0). The FluentAssertions site says .NET Core 2.0 is supported (and I stepped down from 2.1). It works locally, but on the build machine I get the following error:

> The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Errors in D:\a\1\s\ProjectName.Tests.csproj
>       Package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager 4.4.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager 4.4.0 supports:
>         - net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1)
>         - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
>       One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure .NET Core 2.0 implemented .NETStandard 2.0 so should work...

Comment: Also that error is pointing at `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`

Comment: Personally would try the following (as it looks like there is some incorrect dependency finding): https://stackoverflow.com/a/39833423/271106

Comment: Under Dependencies > NuGet > FluentAssertions (5.4.2) there are two items - FluentAssertions.dll and System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager (4.4.0).
And in the NuGet UI under Dependencies for FluentAssertions it shows .NETCoreApp, Version=v2.0 it has one - System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager (>=4.4.0)

Comment: Also have you tried Cleaning out your source on your build server?

Comment: I'm using Azure DevOps... It starts clean every time.

Comment: There is a section on setting up .NET Core on Azure DevOps on MS Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/using-ci-with-cli#ci-setup-examples

Comment: I removed `FluentAssertions` and just used old school `Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);` and everything worked fine. So I wonder if the dependencies are wrong for `FluentAssertions` on `.NETCoreApp`?

Comment: above comments explain: System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the Azure DevOps Build pipeline was using NuGet 4.1.0. I added a task to the pipeline right before the NuGet restore called NuGet Tool Installer and set it to install version 4.4.0. Then everything worked fine. Thanks Dennis Doomen!

Comment: You're welcome. It's a common issue of a lot of problems with PackageReference projects.